# take value of bool and display as checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

Each record in the 'Supplier' table has has a bool 'SupplierEmailProvided' column. To display the value on screen:

```
@Model.Suppliers.Where(s => s.Id == products.PreferredSupplierId).FirstOrDefault().SupplierEmailProvided
```

This works fine, however ATM it displays a 'true' or 'false' (on screen) depending on its value.

I want to change that to a **checkbox, which is disabled if the value is FALSE**

Tried something like:`@Html.CheckBoxFor(s => s.Suppliers.Where(x => x.SupplierEmailProvided)).FirstOrDefault().SupplierEmailProvided'`

but not good. any ideas guys?

**EDIT**
So I have given all suggestions ago.

```
@if((s => s.Id == products.PreferredSupplierId).FirstOrDefault().SupplierEmailProvided)
                     {   
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(s => s.Suppliers
                                                    .Where(x => x.Id == products.PreferredSupplierId)
                                                    .FirstOrDefault()
                                                    .SupplierEmailProvided)

                             @Html.CheckBox("SupplierEmailProvided",true,
                             (Model.Suppliers.Where(x => x.SupplierEmailProvided)).FirstOrDefault().SupplierEmailProvided 
                             ? (object) new { disabled = "false" } : (object) new {disabled = "true" })
                     }
```

the beginning if statment says 'operator '.' cannt be applied to opperad of type lamba?

any help?

Comment: If supplierEmailProvided is nullable you will have to put SupplierEmailProvided.Value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `SupplierEmailProvided` is a boolean type, Haven't tested though logic should be clear

As you have mentioned check box should be in disabled state when value is false.

```
@if(Model.Suppliers.Where(x => x.SupplierEmailProvided)).FirstOrDefault().SupplierEmailProvided)
{
     Html.CheckBox("SupplierEmailProvided",true)
}else
{
     Html.CheckBox("SupplierEmailProvided",false,new{ disabled ="true"} )
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply...problem is when I used your code....all the checkboxes where returning true, and all of them where disabled. I only want the 'false' values to be disabled?? and why are all returning true?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
@if(Model.Suppliers.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == products.PreferredSupplierId).SupplierEmailProvided)
{
    html code 
}
else 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: it says operator '.' cant be applied to operand of type 'lamba expression'

Comment: can't you take this SupplierEmailProvided in a Model and return it when you are returning view and then in view you can directly check if(Model.SupplierEmailProvided).

Answer (score 0):

The `CheckBoxFor` should work, check your brackets, maybe split the assignment in half:

```
@{
    var supplier = Model.Suppliers.Where(s => s.Id == products.PreferredSupplierId).FirstOrDefault();
}
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => supplier.SupplierEmailProvided)
```

Or in one line as you where doing:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Suppliers
                                .Where(s => s.Id == products.PreferredSupplierId)
                                .FirstOrDefault()
                                .SupplierEmailProvided)
```

Comment: ahh nice one. so how do i disable the checkbox if the value is false

Comment: In that case you will need an `if` similar to the one in @d.Siva answer. The use case seems weird honestly, so you want it disabled if it's false but enabled (so users can un-check it) if it is already checked?

Comment: yes the idea is...if its false, the email does not exist. if its true the email does exist in the supplier record...The user can then tick or un tick the same checkbox which will be posted back. If set to true send and email to supplier, if false...no email

Comment: My point being, if it is **disabled** the user cannot tick it... maybe you mean you want it **unchecked** if the email is not there and **checked** if the email is present? Then the single line in my answer should be enough. The `if` as it's written is not working because you need the whole `@Model.Suppliers.Where` part which d.Siva omitted (i'll edit his answer).